# Is it possible to define the center of the current block as a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to place a named node in the center of a beamer `block` environment, so that I can later reference this node using the `remember picture` option. Is there any way to achieve that? I imagine that as beamer blocks are rendered as tikz pictures, it could be possible to somehow get the center (or some other fixed point) of a block. But I don't know enough about beamer's implementation to find out myself.

Comment: Please, ca you provide a sketch, what you like do obtain? Probably the `tikzmark˙ library or package can do what you after.

Comment: Beamer is a bit of a problem in that it formats the title AFTER text, so you really don't know how much space you have to work with.  You might just guess a size (minipage or tikz node) and fit all the text inside.

Answer (score 4):

`beamer` doesn't use `TikZ` but `pgf`. But you can use `tcolorbox` which can `remember` every box and use them as reference.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First slide}

\begin{tcolorbox}[beamer, enhanced, remember as=mybox, title=A nice box]
With some text inside
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[fill=red!30] at (mybox.center) (A) {A node on top};
\draw[->, red, ultra thick] (A)--(mybox.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]